# Call a controller action on click of hyperlink when javascript disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a cshtml with below code,I want to record the link which was clicked by the user,The link might be a external url.This should work even when **javascript** is disabled.

```
foreach (var featuredPod in Model.FeaturedPods)

 {
<a href="@featuredPod.LinkUrl" class="button blue prePopLink @linkClass">Find out more</a>
 }
```

Comment: Yes this should work when javascript is disabled because you'r not calling javascript method, and so what?

Comment: Do you understand the lifecycle of razor pages? You can't detect anything once the view is rendered and passed to the client. Even with Javascript this would not be 100% reliable as the client has full control. You *can* log requests to your controller, though.

Comment: Yes,That's why I have posted this here.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to record what the user clicked , then you will need to process this on the server and redirect the user to the real link

So something like (assuming each featuredPod in the model has some form of Id)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Find out more", "RecordAction", "RedirectController", new {Id=featuredPod.Id}, new {@class="", target="_blank"})
```

Then in the RecordAction action in the RedirectController

```
// get your Model.FeaturedPods where Id = passed in id
// record what the url is somewhere 
Return Redirect(featuredPod.LinkUrl)
```

Comment: Thanks,I didn't think this way.But the link should open in a new tab,it can be achieved in this solution?

Comment: yes - just set target="_blank" in the ActionLink  - answer amended above

Comment: Thanks for the idea,Tweaked the above answer as required,working good.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use **@Html.ActionLink** helper?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Find out more", "Action", "Controller", new {Id=Model.Id}, new {@class="(...)"}
```

Comment: I want to record the link which was clicked by the user,when javascript disabled.
The link wasn't in the current application,it might be external.
The above code just generates a link with anchor tag ,having styles

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I didn't read your inner thoughts,which I understood below comments